# What is best practice for handling resize events in a polymer element?

Tags: events, canvas, resize, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to create a "Viewport" type element extended from a Canvas element. I intended for it to fill the parent container, but that seems not very trivial.

The canvas element does not work with style="width:100%; height:100%" (it will revert to a default value of 300x150 pixels if the special Canvas width and the height attributes are not set, or it will go to 100x100 pixels if I try to set those attributes to "100%". This leaves me with the task of manually setting the width of the canvas element according to the size of the parent element. However I am at a loss when trying to figure out a way to access a resize event I could add a handler to from the perspective of the custom element. I don't seem to get access to window.on.resize from anywhere within the custom element. Do I have to do this from the outside?

Here is an example polymer element definition:

```html
<polymer-element name="canvas-viewport">
  <template>
    <style>
      @host{
        :scope {
          margin:0px;
          padding:0px;
          display:block;
          position:relative;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          background:limegreen;
          overflow:visible;
          border:0;
        }
       }

      div {
        border:0;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }

    </style>
<div id="container">
      <canvas width="{{wpWidth}}" height="{{wpHeight}}" id="theCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="canvas_viewport.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Here is some dart code in the accompanying polymer class definition for trying to handle the resize that I made based on a suggested solution to this question.

```dart
@override
void attached() {
  super.attached();
  viewPortContainer = shadowRoot.querySelector("#container");
  window.onResize.listen(resizecontainer);
}


void resizecontainer(Event e){
  wpWidth = viewPortContainer.clientWidth;
  wpHeight = viewPortContainer.clientHeight;
  print("resizing Width:$wpWidth , Height:$wpHeight ");    
}
```

However this results in a bug where the height grows by three pixels on each resize event, even though margins and paddings are set to zero.

Answer (score 5):

OnResize works for me inside a custom element.

```dart
@override
void attached() {
  super.attached();
  window.onResize.listen((e) {
    print(e.currentTarget.innerWidth); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful- it provides the proper place to put the event handler! However when trying to set the canvas the same width and height that I get from the  container where I placed the canvas element  it seems to expand the containers height by three pixels on each resize event(not the width) I'we set all paddings and margins to 0.

Comment: I implemented a similar thing with camas recently as I posted about in another thread. I'll have to check for the 3px growing issue to see if it affects me too. I'll post back on the weekend w the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will achieve this in Polymer.

```
 connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._onResize = this.onResize.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener("resize", this._onResize);
 }

 onResize(e) {
    console.log('width', e.currentTarget.innerWidth);
 }

 disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this._onResize);
 }
```

Comment: Works in Polymer 2.0 (I only tested in Polymer 2.0)

Comment: It should work in Polymer 3.0 as well, I used it in there.